# SQLite select date and increment selection when points to weekend

Tags: sql, android-sqlite

I want to increment days when I select a date in SQLite and it points to weekends,

here is the code.

```
SELECT strftime('%Y-%d-%m','now', '+9 days');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming what you want Saturdays and Sundays to be the following Monday then the following may do what you wish :-

```
SELECT  CASE  
    WHEN strftime('%w','now') = 0 THEN strftime('%Y-%d-%m','now','+1 days') /* add 1 day when Sunday */
    WHEN strftime('%w','now')= 6 THEN strftime('%Y-%d-%m','now','+2 days') /* add 2 days when Saturday */
    ELSE strftime('%Y-%d-%m','now')
END AS adjusted_date;
```

If not then as you can see %w returns the days of the week where 0 is Sunday and 6 is Saturday. and you can use CASE WHEN THEN ELSE clause to conditionally returns values.

[Date And Time Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Comment: @JulesNicoYabes, that's good. If the answer helped then please tick it as answered.

Comment: HI sir, One more problem, I also need to adjust days when it points to holidays, is there a way to code that in a query?

Comment: @JulesNicoYabes holidays are country/state specific and would be complicated by weekends e.g. Christmas day could be a week day or weekend. You should ask another question in that regard as depedning upon the requirements it can be quite complex but could very likely be accomplished (a table of such dates may be the way to).

Comment: can u please help me with this one?:( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59780122/expandable-listview-with-sqlite-data